# perl extended regex pattern with (condition) behaves wrong, what I do false?

Tags: regex, perl

I use perl --version

perl 5, version 36, subversion 0 (v5.36.0) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int (with 52 registered patches

I have used following test lines with these results:

```
perl -we '$_="ab"; $WE_retcod = $_ =~ m/(?<=a)b/; print "WE_retcod: Y" . $WE_retcod . "Y\n"; print "\&: Y" . $& . "Y\n";'
```

yields

> return code is 1
>
> matched is "b"
>
> ok

```
perl -we '$_="ab"; $WE_retcod = $_ =~ m/(?<=c)b/; print "WE_retcod: Y" . $WE_retcod . "Y\n"; print "\&: Y" . $& . "Y\n";'
```

yields

> return code is empty
>
> matched is uninitialized
>
> ok

```
perl -we '$_="ab"; $WE_retcod = $_ =~ m/(?(?<=a)b)/; print "WE_retcod: Y" . $WE_retcod . "Y\n"; print "\&: Y" . $& . "Y\n";'
```

yields

> return code is 1
>
> matched is empty
>
> false: matched should "b"

```
perl -we '$_="ab"; $WE_retcod = $_ =~ m/(?(?<=c)b)/; print "WE_retcod: Y" . $WE_retcod . "Y\n"; print "\&: Y" . $& . "Y\n";'
```

yields

> return code is 1
>
> matched is empty
>
> false: return code should be empty
>
> match should be uninitialized

What I have made wrong?

Regards

Comment: Is this some kind of test to do on a self-compiled Perl from e.g. a git repository? If yes. Tell about it.

Comment: no self-compiled, normal  perl from distribution Kubuntu 20.04 and KNOPPIX 9.1 Regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted a non-capturing group using `(?:)` around the whole expression in the 3rd and 4th example. If so, the colon is missing in your expression, so the following lines are working.

```
perl -we '$_="ab"; $ret = $_ =~ m/(?:(?<=a)b)/; print "ret: Y" . $ret . "Y\n"; print "\&: Y" . $& . "Y\n";'
perl -we '$_="ab"; $ret = $_ =~ m/(?:(?<=c)b)/; print "ret: Y" . $ret . "Y\n"; print "\&: Y" . $& . "Y\n";'   as intended.
```